# How to see what is on external monitor using built-in screen?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, compiz, external-monitor

I have a laptop connected to external monitor. Everything ok, but sometimes I need to check what's going on on external monitor (because I can't see them), hence two monitor should display the same output for a while. Are there any ways to do so?

Comment: It is unclear. Can you just look at the external monitor and check what is going on there?

Comment: No I can't. I'm behind of it.

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov Not the best solution but you could always use something like OBS to live capture your second screen and view it on the OBS window on your laptop.

Comment: Doesn't the laptop have a function key to switch between built-in and external screen?

Comment: Yes it does, but it have different purpose) so it is not suitable for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy and simple, you can take a screenshot using `print screen` key. It shows both screens.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution if you are using X11 is to take a snapshot of the second display. For example, using `xwd` and assuming the monitor is display screen 0.1,

```
xwd -root -display :0.1 | xwud -in /dev/stdin
```

should show the current screen in a window.

An alternative is to use `x11vnc` and `xvncviewer`.